# How to debug EJB which is deployed on Weblogic

Tags: java, debugging, ejb, weblogic

I have application running on Weblogic. And I have another application which connects to one deployed on Weblogic and uses EJB of it. I am successfully connecting to EJB using JNDI, even my debugger shows that this class is currently launched (but the name is changed - WL added something to end of class name(like if class was AEjb, it shows that launched class is AEjb_krtm_pfff ...)). But I can't see nor variables, nor lines executed. So are there any ways to see what's happening with this EJB class?

Comment: Essentially you need to debug WebLogic server side deployed EJB code?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Had found some tutorial, which I thought would have done it, but those all are outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's no different than the way you are debugging the client side application.** Add your EJB source code also in the debugger path and add a break point on EJB source code which you want to debug.

If your EJB is deployed on different Weblogic server, then you may want to use [**remote debugging**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html) option.

Comment: Thank You! And do this tutorial affects only JDeveloper or I can make this trick with another IDE?

Comment: @JanisKivitis I have been using Eclipse to debug my EJB deployed local or remote Weblogic servers. So I don't think there are any issue as long as your IDE supports remote debugging. If you face any issues, please let me know. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, NetBeans and IntelliJ, all are usefull for some purposes.

Comment: @JanisKivitis: In eclipse, go to `Run -> Dubug Configurations -> Remote Java Applications` and provide the details to attach the debugger with remote server. Also please make sure that your remote server is started with debug port enabled. Please let me know, if you dace any specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to debug the EJB code deployed on the WebLogic server, you can do the debugging using any of the following options:

1. Use remote debugging as suggested by Yogendra
2. If you can control the deployment of the Application containing EJB, then deploy it in exploded directory mode on Administration Server and use JDeveloper Integrated WebLogic Server to debug the source whenever client pings the EJB code deployed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standalone client to call EJB, and have been facing an issue on client side, the same can be debugged using system property on client side.

-Dweblogic.ejb.enhancement.debug=true (post WLS 10.3.1.0)

-Dweblogic.ejb.proxy.debug=true (src branch)